# How to convert em/rem to px?

Tags: css, regex, perl, find-replace

I have a following script which converts px to em:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d+)px/($1\/16).em/ge' stylesheet.css
```

However, when I tweak it to convert em to px then it doesn't work well:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d+)em/($1*16).px/ge' stylesheet.css
```

It converts `2.25em` to `2.400px`. Please help me on this.

Comment: Hint: what is 25 times 16?

Comment: Oh crap! It only converted the decimal part?

Comment: Can you help me with this regular expression man? Can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the fractional part:

- match the integer part (one or more digits `\d+)
- match optionally a fractional part

  - match the dot (`\.`)
  - match the fractional part (one or more digits `\d+`)

```perl
$ echo '2.25em 2em' | perl -pe 's/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)em/($1*16).px/ge'
36px 32px
```

Comment: I improved the answer to make the fractional part optional. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a character group instead [   ]

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d[\d\.]*)px/($1\/16).em/ge'
```

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d[\d\.]*)em/($1*16).px/ge'
```